# Lagrangian of three-mass system with Mathematica

Tags: control-systems, modeling, mechanism

Before proceeding to calculations in Mathematica, I would like to clarify with knowledgeable people.

There is an ordinary linear three-mass system.

[image]

If we write its Lagrangian, we get the following equation.

[image]

where $W_k$ and $W_n$ - kinetic and potential energy.

To find the moment of rotation of the first mass, we must differentiate lagrangian first by the angle of rotation of the first mass $\phi_1$, then find the rate of change in time of the Lagrangian derivative with respect to speed $\omega_1$.

[image]

Suppose we want to find the moment of the first mass $J_1$ (we assume that on the shaft of the drive motor).

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_1} = -c_{12} (\phi_1 - \phi_2)$

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \omega_1} = J_1 \frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial t}$

Which ultimately gives us a dynamic equation:

$M - c_{12} (\phi_1 - \phi_2) = J_1 \frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial t}$

My questions are as follows:

1. Where did the masses of $J_2$ and $J_3$ go? Because we are looking for a derivative and speeds of this masses $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$ do not explicitly depend on $\omega_1$, no matter how massive they are, they do not include into the equation of motion and do not affect the torque M.
2. Do I understand correctly that taking into account the influence of the moments of inertia of the remaining masses $J_2$ and $J_3$ is possible only by bringing the moments of inertia to the motor shaft $J_1$ (by correcting the coefficients of the square of the gear ration).
3. What tools are there in Mathematica for working with mechanical systems, equations of motion, etc.?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a Mathematica question! Usually we prefer something with some mathematica code to work with. You can construct the differential equations and we would be interested in solving them with mathematica. Meantime have a look at this link on [Lagrangian dynamics with Mathematica](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/496/).

Comment: @Sumit - thank you, i will try it.

Comment: I am not clear about how the rotation comes into the problem. The diagram looks like three masses connected by springs with everything in translation. Is the problem actually one of rotation and the springs are providing a torque? Are we meant to see an axis of rotation in the above problem?

Comment: I just want to calculate the driving moment of the first mass using the Lagrange equation.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that when differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to the generalized coordinate (in our case this $\omega_1$, the components of kinetic energy that are not clearly connected with the velocity of the first mass ($\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$) disappear and it turns out that the equation of motion of the first mass does not depend on the masses of the second and subsequent masses.
Look at the Lagrangian and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me derive the equations of motion.

The Lagrangian:

```
L = Sum[1/2 Subscript[J, i] D[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], t]^2, {i, 3}] -
   Sum[1/2 Subscript[c, 
    10 i + i + 
     1] (Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t])^2, {i,
     2} ]
```

> [image]

The equations of motion:

```
TableForm[
 eqns = Table[
    D[D[L, Derivative[1][q][t]], t] - D[L, q[t]] == 
     Subscript[τ, q][t], 
         {q, {Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ, 2], 
      Subscript[ϕ, 3]}}] /. 
       {Subscript[τ, Subscript[ϕ, 1]][t] -> M[t], 
    Subscript[τ, Subscript[ϕ, 2]][t] -> 0, 
         Subscript[τ, Subscript[ϕ, 3]][t] -> 0}]
```

> [image]

A state-space representation:

```
asys=AffineStateSpaceModel[
 AffineStateSpaceModel[
  eqns, {Subscript[ϕ, 1][t], Subscript[ϕ, 2][t], 
   Subscript[ϕ, 3][t], Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 1]][t], 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 2]][t], 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 3]][t]}, 
  M[t], {Subscript[ϕ, 1][t], Subscript[ϕ, 2][t], 
   Subscript[ϕ, 3][t], Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 1]][t], 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 2]][t], 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 3]][t]}, 
  t], {Subscript[ϕ, 1][t], Subscript[ϕ, 2][t], 
  Subscript[ϕ, 3][t], Subscript[w, 1][t], Subscript[w, 2][t], 
  Subscript[w, 3][t]}]
```

> [image]

I think in the first question you are asking if the input torque has any effect on the the second and third masses. From the 4th equation we can see that the input affects $w_1$. The bigger the mass the more the effort involved will be because $J_1$ is in the denominator. $w_1$ affects $\phi_1$. $\phi_1$ affects $w_2$, which affects $\phi_2$. $\phi_2$ affects $w_3$ which affects $\phi_3$. There is also some coupling in the sense that not only does $w_1$ affects $\phi_1$ but $\phi_1$ as well, etc. Also as I mentioned before the heavier the masses, the less some these influences will be.

Alternatively, you could just ask if all the positions and velocities can be adjusted using the torque on the first mass.

```
ControllableModelQ[%]
```

> True

If we look a the transfer function we see that all the variables depend on all the inertia terms.

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[asys, s]
```

> [image]

The generalized force is $M[t]$. From the last element of the transfer function which is that for $\frac{w_3(s)}{M(s)}$ we can obtain the following relationship for the generalized force.

```
M[s] /. Solve[Subscript[w, 3][s]/M[s] == 
    SystemsModelExtract[tfm, 1, -1][s][[1, 1]], M[s]][[1]];

InverseLaplaceTransform[% /. 
  Subscript[w, 3][s] -> LaplaceTransform[Subscript[w, 3][t], t, s], s, t]/. _[0] -> 0
```

> [image]

Lastly, you can see examples of such systems in [AffineStateSpaceModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html#1840712218) and related documentation.

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13173/inertia-referred-to-motor-shaft

Comment: Imagine that the first mass is connected to the second via a gearbox with a gear ratio of $ n_1 $, and the second mass is connected to the third through a gearbox with a gear ratio of $ n_2 $. Now try to write in the Lagrangian instead of the velocities and angles of the second and third masses not $ \omega_2 $ and $ \omega_3 $ ($ \phi_2 $ and $ \phi_3 $ for angles), but $ \omega_1 / n_1 $ and $ \omega_1 / ( n_1 * n_2) $ ($ \phi_1 / n_1 $ and $ \phi_1 / (n_1 * n_2) $ for angles). Isn't this the way to go?

Comment: Let's say I want to find the moment needed to rotate this whole structure. By such differentiation of the Lagrangian, it turns out that the moment of the drive motor depends only on the intrinsic moment of inertia and acceleration, which, to put it mildly, is strange.

Comment: @AndrewSol, I think I am not understanding your confusion. I get that if you add gears the variables have to be scaled. Try `SystemsModelExtract[TransferFunctionModel[affine model, s], All, 1]` and you will see that $\phi_1$ depends on all the inertias. If this is not the issue, could you reformulate your question.

Comment: I am interested in the generalized force (moment) of the first mass. Try to manually differentiate the Lagrangian by the generalized coordinates of the first mass and you will understand me.

Comment: The generalized force on the first mass is $M$, which from the transfer function is $\frac{a}{b}$, where $b=c_{12} c_{23}$ and $a=c_{12} c_{23} J_1 \phi _3'(t)+c_{12} c_{23} J_2 \phi _3'(t)+c_{12} c_{23} J_3 \phi _3'(t)+c_{23} J_1 J_2 \phi
   _3{}^{(3)}(t)+c_{12} J_1 J_3 \phi _3{}^{(3)}(t)+c_{23} J_1 J_3 \phi _3{}^{(3)}(t)+c_{12} J_2 J_3 \phi
   _3{}^{(3)}(t)+J_1 J_2 J_3 \phi _3{}^{(5)}(t)$.

Comment: This formula does not follow from operations with the Lagrangian.

Comment: I got it from the Lagrangian. You have to consider all the equations.

Comment: Strange thing is that this does not involve the operation of bringing the moments of inertia to the motor shaft..[6.4.Referring moment of inertia](https://books.google.ru/books?id=YikAs8Bp0yYC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=refferng+moment+of+inertia+to+shaft&source=bl&ots=RLnyPCe-5S&sig=ACfU3U0M-jX2tSDaX13qjxlJdkgsyNG8Tw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqkIrF5oTnAhXMJlAKHVYeD_AQ6AEwFHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=refferng%20moment%20of%20inertia%20to%20shaft&f=false)

Comment: @ Suba Thomas - how did you get this transfer function?

Comment: I showed the transfer function a couple of comments above, but then I made a typo in a subsequent comment. It should be $w_3$ and not $\phi_3$. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I have a question. When we get the transfer function, then we can represent it in the form of a state space. Is it possible to find some kind of expansion for matrix $A$ to separate the stiffnesses $c_{ij}$ and moments of inertia $J_i$?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The state-space is a first-order vector matrix equation where these are not separated. The standard Lagrangian form or the Kane's formulation separates the inertia and stiffness terms.

Comment: Is it possible to demonstrate this in Mathematica? This separation is very useful to me, i.e. simplifies work with variable moments of inertia

Comment: `vars = {Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t], Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t], Subscript[\[Phi], 3][t]};
dVars = D[vars, t];
d2Vars = D[dVars, t];`

`D[Subtract @@@ eqns, {d2Vars}] (* generalized mass matrix *)`

`D[Subtract @@@ eqns, {dVars}] (* generalized damping matrix *)`

`D[Subtract @@@ eqns, {vars}] (* generalized stiffness matrix *)`

`-Subtract @@@ eqns /. Thread[Join[vars, dVars, d2Vars] -> 0] (* generalized forces*)`

Comment: Is there results correct? https://ibb.co/d6qWdCG

Comment: Put each  `D[...](*...*)` and the final `-Subtract...` in a new line. I was not able to convey that properly in the comment above.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean by 'non-stationary', but can you obtain Lagrange's equations for such non-stationary moments of inertia?

Comment: And how include gear ratios in Lagrangian ?

Comment: If $r$ is a gear ratio, you simply can write one angular velocity in terms of the other as $\omega _1=r \ \omega _2$ and make that substitution in the Lagrangian. It's straightforward?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250286/equations-of-motion-for-two-mass-torsional-oscillator-with-the-gear-train

Comment: But then it turns out that the Lagrangian depends on only one velocity? And the second generic coordinate will disappear?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250700/lagrangian-including-vector-and-matrices-operations

Comment: Please see the question in your free time  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271830/equations-of-motion-with-gear-ratios-through-the-lagrangian-with-an-unknown-tran

Answer (score 3):

Below is the equation of motion of the system given in OP. You need to use the variational package in Mathematica. The equation of motion is arrived at without considering the rotational inertia. And use NDsove to find the system solution.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
<< VariationalMethods`
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
T = 0.5*m1*(D[x1[t], {t, 1}])^2 + 0.5*m2*(D[x2[t], {t, 1}])^2 + 
   0.5*m3*(D[x3[t], {t, 1}])^2;
V = 0.5*Subscript[C, 12]*(x1[t] - x2[t])^2 + 
   0.5*Subscript[C, 23]*(x2[t] - x3[t])^2;
Lg = T - V;
e1 = EulerEquations[Lg, {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t}];
e2 = FullSimplify[e1[[1]]]
e3 = FullSimplify[e1[[2]]]
e4 = FullSimplify[e1[[3]]]
```

Comment: how adequate is the result of calculating the generalized forces?

Comment: And why is the second and third mass not affected by the equation of motion of the first mass?

Comment: @AndrewSol  you have to do the future analysis to check whether the result is adequate or not.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that when differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to the generalized coordinate (in our case this $\omega_1$, the components of kinetic energy that are not clearly connected with the velocity of the first mass ($\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$) disappear and it turns out that the equation of motion of the first mass does not depend on the masses of the second and subsequent masses.
Look at the Lagrangian and see for yourself.