# Equations of motion for two-mass torsional oscillator with the gear train

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems, mechanism

This is my first topic and I continue work on that: [Lagrangian of three-mass system with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212848/lagrangian-of-three-mass-system-with-mathematica)

I found interesting problem [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/show-following-system-2nd-order-ordinary-differential-equations-represents-dynamics-two-ma-q6952677), and try reproduce results.

[image]

*Assumption:* $d_1=0$

**Algorithm:**

1. Write Lagrangian:

$L=W_k-W_p=\frac{J_1 \omega_1^2}{2}+\frac{J_2 (\frac{r_2}{r_1}\omega_2)^2}{2}-\frac{c_1(\phi_1-\frac{r_2}{r_1}\phi_2)^2}{2}$

where $W_k$ and $W_n$ - kinetic and potential energy.

2. Using formula:

[image]

find equation of motion for coordinates:

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi_1}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_1}=0$

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi_2}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_2}=0$

I implemented all this in Mathematica:

```
Clear["Derivative"];

ClearAll["Global`*"];

Remove[c, J, r];

L = Sum[1/2 Subscript[J, i] D[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], t]^2, {i, 2}] -
    Sum[1/2 Subscript[c, 
      10 i + i + 
       1] (Subscript[\[Phi], i][t] - 
        Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t])^2, {i, 1}];


L = -(1/2) Subscript[c, 
    12] (Subscript[\[Phi], 1][
       t] - ((Subscript[r, 2]/Subscript[r, 1]) Subscript[\[Phi], 2][
         t]))^2 + 
   1/2 Subscript[J, 1] Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 1]][t]^2 + 
   1/2 Subscript[J, 
    2] ((Subscript[r, 2]/Subscript[r, 1]) Derivative[1][
       Subscript[\[Phi], 2]][t])^2;

eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 1]][t]], t] - 
  D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]]
eq2 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 2]][t]], t] - 
  D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]]
```

**But the results didn't match the picture. Where did I go wrong?**

[image]

**EDIT:**

There is my code for three-mass system:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

Remove[c, J]

(***Gear ratios)

gr = {Subscript[n, 1], Subscript[n, 2]};

L = Sum[1/2 Subscript[J, i] D[Subscript[\[Phi], i][t], t]^2, {i, 3}] -
    Sum[1/2 Subscript[c, 
      10 i + i + 
       1] (Subscript[\[Phi], i][t]/gr[[i]] - 
        Subscript[\[Phi], i + 1][t])^2, {i, 2}];


eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 1]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]] == Subscript[T, 1][t] // Simplify;
eq20 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 2]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]] == Subscript[T, 2][t] // Simplify;
eq3 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 3]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 3][t]] == Subscript[T, 3][t] // Simplify;

eq2 = ApplySides[Expand[Subscript[n, 1]^2*#1] &, 
   eq20 /. Subscript[n, 1] -> 1/Subscript[n, 1]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gr =.; (*Subscript[r, 2]/Subscript[r, 1]*) 
igr =.; (*Subscript[r, 1]/Subscript[r, 2]*)
twist = -gr*Subscript[ϕ, 2][t] - Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]; 

L = Sum[(1/2)*Subscript[J, i]*D[Subscript[ϕ, i][t], t]^2, {i, 2}] - 
    (1/2)*Subscript[c, 1]*twist^2; 

eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 1]][t]], t] - D[L, Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]] == 
      Subscript[T, 1][t] + Subscript[d, 1]*D[twist, t]//Expand
eq20 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[ϕ, 2]][t]], t] - D[L, Subscript[ϕ, 2][t]] == 
      Subscript[T, 2][t] + Subscript[d, 1]*D[twist, t]*gr; 
eq2 = ApplySides[Expand[igr^2*#1] & , eq20 /. gr -> 1/igr]
```

> $c_1 \text{gr} \phi _2(t)+c_1 \phi _1(t)+J_1 \phi _1''(t)=-d_1 \text{gr} \phi _2'(t)-d_1 \phi _1'(t)+T_1(t)\\c_1 \text{igr} \phi _1(t)+c_1 \phi _2(t)+\text{igr}^2 J_2 \phi _2''(t)=-d_1 \text{igr} \phi _1'(t)-d_1 \phi _2'(t)+\text{igr}^2 T_2(t)$

Comment: How can this approach be extended to the case of three-mass systems?

Comment: just for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPodJ.gif

Comment: and it is natural that the gear ratios $N_1=\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$ and $N_2=\frac{\omega_2}{\omega_3}$

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's two, three or more masses. Just add the additional terms to the Lagrangian and the generalized forces, and use the gear ratios in terms of the radii to eliminate the intermediate velocities.

Comment: I will try to do it myself, only instead of gear ratios I will use not the ratio of the radii, but simply the designations of the gear ratios $N_1...N_3$

Comment: Please see my code for a three-mass system. 

I also assumed that the rigid shafts are installed after the gearboxes, and not in front of them.

The only thing that didn't work for me was to apply a line of code. 
`ApplySides[Expand[igr^2*#1] & , eq20 /. gr -> 1/igr]`
For some reason, the expression is not modified with it.

Comment: Please add a figure to show what you mean by 'after the gearboxes'. [`ApplySides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplySides.html) has been in the WL since 11.3. What is the output you are getting and is it the same as `eq20`? And what version are you using and which OS?

Comment: "after gearboxes" https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEzU.png

Comment: `eq1 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 1]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]] == Subscript[T, 1][t] // Simplify;`
`eq20 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 2]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]] == Subscript[T, 2][t] // Simplify;`
`eq3 = D[D[L, Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Phi], 3]][t]], t] - 
     D[L, Subscript[\[Phi], 3][t]] == Subscript[T, 3][t] // Simplify;`

`eq2 = ApplySides[Expand[Subscript[n, 1]^2*#1] &, 
   eq20 /. Subscript[n, 1] -> 1/Subscript[n, 1]];`

Comment: Help us figure it out, please. We discussed the issue with one user and were at a dead end.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130663/discussion-between-cesareo-and-dtn