# Derivation of equations of motion for a multi-body system using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mechanism

I want to learn how to work with finite-element models in Mathematica to derive the equation of motion for rigid bodies.

I can do this by compiling the Lagrangian of the system, then differentiating by generalized coordinates, as was done in the topics:

[Lagrangian of three-mass system with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212848/lagrangian-of-three-mass-system-with-mathematica)

[Equations of motion for two-mass torsional oscillator with the gear train](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250286/equations-of-motion-for-two-mass-torsional-oscillator-with-the-gear-train)

This time I want to program all the relationships and types of motion, and the derivation of the equations of motion should be carried out automatically.

Several tools caught my eye, but I haven't worked with that yet:

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/slider-crank-mechanism.html

https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mechsystems/screens.html

https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/linkagedesigner/examples.html

There is a tripod robot with one triangular fixed platform and one triangular movable platform. The position of the platform is changed by linear movement of the drive links:

[image]

Need to:

1.Build up kinematic scheme in Mahematica (by analogy with how it is done in SimMechanics or SimScape MultiBody);

2. Derive the Lagrangian $L$ automaticly;
3. Derive the equations of motion automaticly;

Is it possible in Mathematica?

Comment: Wolfram SystemModeler creates equations of motion for connected components and simulates them. In Mathematica, you can use SystemModel to create such models. And access their equations, among other properties. Although those equations tend to involve lots of extra variables, so not easy to interpret.

Comment: dtn, tagging a user that has not commented on the post yet will not notify them, just fyi. I it might help to mention it to them in chat if you’d like to get their attention.

Comment: @CATrevillian I am very grateful, the help of specialists will be useful to me

Comment: @tad equation of motion in symbolic form ?

Comment: @CATrevillian now, I need something like this, but I did not understand how to get the equations of motion in symbolic form?
https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/examples/industrial-manufacturing/stewart-platform-parallel-manipulator.html

Comment: Yes, you can get symbolic form of equations. See the "SystemEquations" property of a SystemModel. You can use these equations, e.g., with NDSolve. There will likely be many more equations and variables than you expect, due to many trivial equations equating connector variables. Human-friendly equations may require some string processing to simplify variable names & remove trivial cases.

Comment: @tad Could you take the time and work with me on this (using the example of the robot from the start topic)? I've never used these tools before, so I need an initial push. where can i start?

Comment: How about starting with simpler examples in SystemModel documentation to see how to extract equations. Creating the 3D mechanical model in the question is probably best to make use of the 3D mechanical components in the Modelica Standard Library. You can drag-and-drop those components if you have Wolfram SystemModeler (or other Modelica-based GUI). Otherwise, you can create 'by hand' using System Model functions in Mathematica, but that will be more work.

Comment: @tad can they be transferred to Mathematica, for example, from SolidWorks?

Comment: I don't know. Mathematica can import many file formats. Most likely one of those matches what SolidWorks can export.

Comment: @tad I could not show you how this is done with a simple example (for example, a pendulum)?
I want to compare the resulting equations of motion with what mathematica suggests.

Comment: Have a look at the video on "Automatically Generate Physical Properties from CAD Data" at https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/what-is-new/

Comment: that video shows both Mathematica importing STL file and System Modeler GUI to make a nice graphic. You can get model properties, such as system equations, directly within Mathematica.