# Optimization when actively working with the NDSolve command

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, dynamic, nonlinear, multivalued

[Lagrangian of three-mass system with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212848/lagrangian-of-three-mass-system-with-mathematica)

Based on the Lagrangian of a mechanical system, we can obtain a system of equations of motion. These equations can be explored numerically using the NDSolve command. They include both the design parameters of the mechanism (overall dimensions, etc.) and the moments of inertia calculated on their basis, etc.

Is it possible, in the process of using the NDSolve command, to find the optimal values of the parameters of the mechanical system according to the selected criterion (for example, the minimum moments of inertia, maximum torques, etc.?).

Comment: Probably yes. Look for  `ParametricNDSolve` and optimize this parameter dependent solution

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can this be done even if there are several parameters?

Comment: Yes that's possible. It appears to be an interesting problem. Why didn't you provide a minimal working example to get more helpful hints??

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I will supplement the question with new information. In the meantime, I'm working on it.